# Cross join to get all quarter end months for specific month in particular year

Tags: sql, teradata

I tried to code logic to get below output but with no success. My mind
 now running blank. Can you share with me your ideas ? I am sure together we
 could figure out some of the simplest solutions in SQL to get the below
 output.

Adding more, I do not want Q4 keys. 
 Please note, the table is a Month dimension containing few more columns such a
 Prev01, 02 ... month keys.

Tagged with SQL Server & Teradata as well as I am concerned with the logic only & not the syntax. I am using Teradata.

**Existing data:**

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

So total expected records for a year would be 12*3 = 36.

**EDIT :** For every year, we have estimate & budget values. For ex.

For 2016, the estimate values will come from March-2016 (Q1), June-2016 (Q2), September-2016 (Q3). And one budget value that will be from December-2015 (Q4). 
So any month from 2016 would have the same budget-estimate values. This will change only if the year changes. I hope it is clear now ...

Unfortunately I would not be able to share the table DDLs or sample data. So tried to explain the scenario as simple as possible. I am able to code SQL to get the budget values, but for the estimates, scenario is bit tricky. So lets say for April-2016, the estimate values I want are March-2016, June-2016, September-2016.
Existing data is a screenshot similar to the sample data.

Adding more, month key is like an identity column. Jan-2017 would have month key as 13 & so on ...

Comment: It looks, `Quarter_End` contains **count of months from JAN**.

Comment: Please share the relevant table DDL statement and sample data as DML. You've been here for a while, you should know by now it's better to share code then images.

Comment: It is not clear what you actually want. We don't know why you show January along with March, June and September. Why not with August for instance? Is there a rule that applies here? Then there are columns quarter_start and quarter_end, the values of which don't seem to make much sense. In the table it seems to be simply the number of the yearly quarter a month resides in. In the results it seems to be either the number of the joined month or the month_key of the joined month. I don't know which.

Comment: Whether the results show month numbers or month_keys is hard to say, because you only show table data for 2016. It might be good to also show a 2015 and a 2017 record from your table. Or does it contain 2016 only? If that were the case, why would it contain a year column at all?

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` tag as you are apparently not using that. Also, please read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: What is the expexted output for later months like december 2016 if you don't want Q4? Is the `month_key` the actual key of the table or just the months within year?

Comment: I explained my question in detail now. Please see Edit. Thank you for the shared ideas. :)

Comment: @v́̎̈́̀̽̏̿̏͋, Quarter_Start are the month keys. Quarter_End I want to get as it is not there in time dimension table. I want Quarter_End to be the month key. 3, 6, 9 points to Month keys in existing data screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here it is

```
select t1.month_key, t1.Month, Year, t3.Month+'-'+right(CAST(Year as varchar(4)),2) Scenario, t2.month_key Quarter_End
from YourData t1
cross join (
    select Quarter_Start, MAX(month_key) month_key
    from YourData
    group by Quarter_Start
) t2
join (
    select month_key, Month
    from YourData   
) t3 on t2.month_key = t3.month_key
where t2.month_key<>12 -- if you do not want last quarter
order by 1,5
```

Comment: Thanks. Something which helped me to build my own !

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL , we can do as follows:

```
declare @temp table (month_key int,Months varchar(100),Years int,Quarter_Start int)
insert into @temp values (1 ,'Jan',2016, 1  )
insert into @temp values (2 ,'Feb',2016, 1  )
insert into @temp values (3 ,'Mar',2016, 1  )
insert into @temp values (4 ,'Apr',2016, 2  )
insert into @temp values (5 ,'May',2016, 2  )
insert into @temp values (6 ,'Jun',2016, 2  )
insert into @temp values (7 ,'Jul',2016, 3  )
insert into @temp values (8 ,'Aug',2016,  3 )
insert into @temp values (9 ,'Sep',2016,  3 )
insert into @temp values (10,'Oct',2016,  4 )
insert into @temp values (11,'Nov',2016,   4)
insert into @temp values (12,'Dec',2016,   4)

select 1 as 'Month_Key','Jan' as 'Month',Years,Months+'-16' as 'Scenario',month_key as 'Quarter End' from @temp where month_key in
(select max(month_key) from @temp group by Quarter_Start)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this is very specific to the sample data provided. I was needed a generic solution : )